# Searching Excel Document Columns with Visual Basic and Interop

Tags: sql, vb.net, excel

I'm struggling with a problem that involves interop and excel. 
Basically, I have excel files with columns that contain "headers" and the rows beneath the columns have the data. For example, the column Age will have 12,14,etc underneath it. I am new to Interop and I'm trying to allow the user to enter the name of the column header they wish to extract data from, so if they enter "Age", it'll find age is colum B for example and then extract all the data from the proceeding rows.

I've Googled extensively and haven't found anything solid, all rather context orientated and being new to Interop makes this a little tricky.

What I've got so far:

```
Public Sub getExcelData(ByVal directory As String)
    Dim excelAppFirstFile As Excel.Application = Nothing
    excelAppFirstFile = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Try
        excelAppFirstFile.Workbooks.Open(directory)
        Dim excelSheet As Excel.Worksheet = excelAppFirstFile.Worksheets(1)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("There was a problem: " + ex.Message)
    End Try


End Sub
```

I know it isn't much but I've gone in circles with ranges,etc and can't figure out how to get where I need to. 
EDIT:
I forgot to add that the Column name being searched for is a variable called field which is set at an earlier stage by the user.

Comment: http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_read_excel.html seems to be what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is **read data** in the Excel file, I suggest you to use **OleDb** instead of interop (which is much faster):

```
Dim filePath As String = "C:\Book1.xls"
Dim connectionString As String = (Convert.ToString("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=") & filePath) + ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0"";"
Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
Dim cmdText As String = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
Dim command As New OleDbCommand(cmdText, connection)

command.Connection.Open()
Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

If reader.HasRows Then
    While reader.Read()
        Console.WriteLine("{0}" & vbTab & "{1}", reader(0).ToString(), reader(1).ToString())
    End While
End If
```